# Debug es6 transpiled code using node-inspector or babel-node-debug

Tags: node.js, debugging, babeljs, node-inspector, node-debugger

When I debug my node rest api, I try to use node-inspector

`node-inspector`

`node --debug server.js`

This way I can debug my api using localhost:3000/api...
If I use node-debug, there's no way. It doens't start port 3000.

However my code is ES6, so in my current debug my code is transpiled by Babel.

I've tried to use babel-node-debug but It seems too be the same situation I had with node-debug. I can see ES6 code, but I'm not able to debug through port 3000.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 3):

The options for `babel-node` (included in the `babel-cli` package) are the same as for `node`.

1. Specify the port for `babel-node`

`babel-node --debug-brk=8010 test.js`

2. Start `node-inspector`

`node-inspector`

3. Navigate to the `node-inspector` URL, passing the same port as a query parameter

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/?port=8010`

I have tried this and it works well for me.

Disclaimer - I found this information here:
https://github.com/CrabDude/babel-node-debug/issues/6